# How do I validate my email submission on php?

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I'm just getting into coding and put together a webpage using dreamweaver. I created a php page with my email coding which is executed from a form and submit button on an html page. I continously recieve blank emails on a daily basis which apparently means I need to add validation coding. I tried adding the coding but the problem persists. The page still submits even if the form is blank.

Below is my current coding.

```html
<?php

if(!filter_var($_POST['CustomerEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { $valerrors[] = "The email address you supplied is invalid." ;}
$customeremail=$_POST['CustomerEmail'];
$email='test@gmail.com';
$custfirst=$_POST['CustomerFirstName'];
$custlast=$_POST['CustomerLastName'];
$custphone=$_POST['CustomerNumber'];
$custaddress=$_POST['CustomerAddress'];
$custcity=$_POST['CustomerCity'];
$custstate=$_POST['CustomerState'];
$custrequest=$_POST['CustomerService'];

$subject='Service Request';

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $customeremail <br>
First Name: $custfirst <br>
Last Name: $custlast <br>
Phone: $custphone <br>
Address: $custaddress <br>
City: $custcity <br>
State: $custstate <br>
Request: $custrequest <br>
EOD;



$headers = "From: $customeremail\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$Send = mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
$confirmation = <<<EOD
<html>"Thanks for Submitting."</html>
EOD;
echo"$confirmation";



?>
```

It's possible that I'm placing the if statement in the wrong place. Can someone correct my coding so the confirmation page will not load and the email will not be sent if the customer email is left blank?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check like this

```
if (filter_var('abc@gmail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    echo 'VALID'; 
} else {
    echo 'NOT VALID';
}
```

see here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize `$valerrors = [];` at the beginning and use a condition such as:

```
if (empty($valerrors)) { 
    $headers = "From: $customeremail\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $Send = mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $confirmation = <<<EOD
    <html>"Thanks for Submitting."</html>
    EOD;
}
```

Note that you should apply similar validation to all user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can add "required" attribute to your email input in your form Html

```
<input type="email" name="CustomerEmail" required>
```

So Html wont allow you to submit until you provide a value

Comment: Thank you! So far this helped. I don't know how I overlooked such a simple command. I'm not sure if this will stop the automatic emails I continously get on a daily basis. I'll have to wait. Thanks again.